# Android DrawerLayout - actionbar changes color to near white

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, drawerlayout

We have an app that uses ActionBarSherlock.  The action bar's background is a drawable that is created at runtime so we can change the color.

I want to add the DrawerLayout.  In my testing, sometimes the background color changes to a near-white.  If I set the text to be #FFF it looks whiter than the background.

I can get this to reproduce if I have the menu launch an activity, and then I hit back.  It seems to happen other times too - might have to do with the device going to sleep.

If the action bar turns white, and I open up the drawer, then it redraws itself to be the right background color.  I've set breakpoints in ADT, and it seems like the methods get called when I want, so I don't know what is triggering the color change.

Is it a problem with the DrawerLayout, is ABS not ready to use DrawerLayout, or do I need to do something additional like invalidate some view for the color to always appear correctly?

EDIT:
I think this solved it.  I'll keep testing.

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    drawerToggle.syncState();
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: Whenever you add a view to your layout, I always put invalidate after adding it to the layout.  Try to run invalidate after you add it to the layout.

Comment: Invalidate which component?

Comment: I personally have not used ActionBarSherlock but if you are adding a view at run-time, just use invalidate on it after.

Comment: I had this same problem with the Android app compat version of the action bar, but without any custom layouts, just using the standard support action bar, and it would go white if I scrolled a dynamically created view underneath it, then hit back.  Your solution worked for me.  Thanks!